# Перевернуть таблицу (Pivot)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть простая таблица:

```
[name]  [value]
цвет    синий
размер  35
форма   куб
```

Как повернуть таблицу, чтобы получилось так:

```
[цвет] [размер] [форма]
синий     35      куб
```

**UPD**

PIVOT конечно классная штука, на одном наборе данных работает, но как быть если наборов данных несколько ?
например:

```
[name]  [value]
цвет    синий
размер  35
форма   куб
цвет    красный
размер  10
форма   шар
```

проблема в том что PIVOT требует чтобы была агрегирующая функция, к примеру если использовать MIN(), то на выходе будет:

```
[цвет] [размер] [форма]
красный   10      куб
```

а должно быть 2 строки:

```
[цвет] [размер] [форма]
синий     35      куб
красный   10      шар
```

Comment: Чтобы PIVOT работал нормально, в таблице кроме [name] и [value] должен быть ключ [key] (простой или составной), идентифицирующий объект, к которому привязаны свойства. По нему будет идти группировка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать оператор Pivot. Вот пример использования взятый [отсюда](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
    -- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Обычный select:

```
DaysToManufacture          AverageCost

0                          5.0885

1                          223.88

2                          359.1082

4                          949.4105
```

С Pivot:

```
Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days    0         1         2           3       4       

AverageCost                       5.0885    223.88    359.1082    NULL    949.4105
```

Comment: PIVOT конечно классная штука, на одном наборе данных работает, но как быть если наборов данных несколько ?

Comment: А вас не смущают разные типы данных в одном столбце?

Comment: по идее все можно примести к одному типу, например преобразовать в строку. но в идеале в наборе не хватает идентификатора по которому можно сгруппировать элементы одного набора, у строк обычно это ID. допустим такой объединяющий ключ есть. можно ли что-то с этим сделать ?

Comment: Это надо будет составлять сложный запрос с подзапросами, если считать что данные идут в определенном порядке.